# Syntax error with $ anchor in regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, syntax-error

The following Ruby script results in a syntax error:

```
test = 'Hello world#'
test.sub!(/#$/, '!')
p test
```

I'd expect the output to be `"Hello world!"`. From my understanding, the regex should match any hash character at the end of a line. Then `sub!` should replace it with an exclamation point.

Instead, I'm getting the following error message:

```
tmp.rb:2: unterminated regexp meets end of file
tmp.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
p test
      ^
```

It seems that the regex still continues after the second slash. If I change the regex to `/#/` (without the trailing `$`), it works as expected.

Comment: try `p test.sub(/#$/, '!')`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Exactly the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby `#` is used for interpolation and to add comments to the regexp.

Just escape the `#` to `\#`:

```
test = 'Hello world#'
test.sub!(/\#$/, '!')
#=> "Hello world!"
```

Comment: That works. But why? '#' is not a special character in any regex implementation I know. And it's not listed as a metacharacter in the official Ruby documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Metacharacters+and+Escapes

Comment: @DanielWolf: In Ruby `#` is used for interpolation and to add comments to the regexp.

Comment: BTW, the alternative regex literal would also work: `%r{#$}`

Comment: @spickermann: Thank you. That makes sense. Can you make that part of your answer rather than a comment (ideally with a documentation link), then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I think the combination of `#` and `$` confused the parser. `$` could refer to a global variable, e.g. `/#$foo/` would interpolate `$foo`. Furthermore, `$/` is a pre-defined global variable. The whole expression is ambiguous.